# Pattern match on constructor supplied as a parameter

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

I have a type something like this:

```
data MyType = I Int | C Char -- and lots of other options
```

I want to be able to find out if a value of this type is a specific variant. I could define functions `isInt`, `isChar`, and so on using pattern matching. But I'd rather be able to write just one function, something like this:

```
hasBaseType :: MyType -> (a -> MyType) -> Bool
hasBaseType (f _) = True
hasBaseType _     = False
```

I would pass the appropriate constructor (`I` or `C`) as the second parameter. Unfortunately, you can't pattern match like that.

I also want to "unwrap" the value. I could write the funtions `unwrapInt`, `unwrapChar`, and so on, again using pattern matching. But I'd rather be able to write just one function, something like this:

```
unwrap :: MyType -> (a -> MyType) -> a
unwrap (f x) = x
unwrap _     = error "wrong base type"
```

Is there some fancy type magic that would allow me to do this? I thought maybe `PatternSynonyms` would help here, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: would a type class not be enough? Instead of your MyType I mean.

Comment: You might like [A Crossroads at a Branch](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/crossroad.xhtml), which is an exploration of this style of programming (okay, specifically, a manifesto against this style).

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll find these functions unwieldy in practice, but this can be accomplished with generics.  Using `Data.Data` seems easiest.  All you need to do for `hasBaseType` is use the supplied pattern to construct a skeleton value of `MyType` (i.e., using `undefined` as the field) and compare the constructors:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data

data MyType = I Int | C Char deriving (Data)

hasBaseType :: MyType -> (a -> MyType) -> Bool
hasBaseType val pat = toConstr val == toConstr (pat undefined)
```

The `unwrap` function is a little trickier, but you can query and cast the first field of the constructor.  The `fromJust` is safe here because `hasBaseType` has ensured that we've got the right field type:

```
import Data.Maybe

unwrap :: (Typeable a) => MyType -> (a -> MyType) -> a
unwrap val pat
  | hasBaseType val pat = gmapQi 0 (fromJust . cast) val
  | otherwise = error "wrong base type"
```

The full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import Data.Maybe

data MyType = I Int | C Char deriving (Data)

hasBaseType :: MyType -> (a -> MyType) -> Bool
hasBaseType val pat = toConstr val == toConstr (pat undefined)

unwrap :: (Typeable a) => MyType -> (a -> MyType) -> a
unwrap val pat
  | hasBaseType val pat = gmapQi 0 (fromJust . cast) val
  | otherwise = error "wrong base type"

main = do
  print $ unwrap (C 'a') C  -- 'a'
  print $ unwrap (I 10) I   -- 10
  print $ unwrap (I 10) C   -- throws "wrong base type" error
```